# Make a HTTP request UDP-like

Tags: node.js

I'm working with AWS Lambda and I'd like to know if there is way to make a HTTP request but without waiting for the response?

I just want to ping a remote service, triggering an event but I don't care if the logic triggered by the event fails or not. At least not from within the first service at the origin of the request.

Comment: In node.js, there's no waiting for a response anyway as its async.  The rest of your code is free to run anyway so just send your response and forget about it.  When it eventually returns, the socket will be cleaned up.  There's nothing to do other than send the http request and then be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#timeouts) explains the use of timeout.

And this is example:

```
const request = require('request');

request.get('http://some/url/here', {timeout: 100}, () =>{console.log('request sent');});
```

p.s. keep in mind that in nodejs such operations are asynchronous, so You don't  have to wait for an answer.

but if it's express app and You want to quickly respond to frontend or thirdparties, so checkout this example:

```
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/some/route', (req, res) => {
  request.get('http://some/url/here', () =>{});
  res.status(202).send('Request accepted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want. It will invoke the callback as soon as the request has been sent (or an error occurs).

```
function udpHttp (options, cb) {
  return require('http')
    .request(options)
    .on('error', cb)
    .end(() => cb(null))
}
```

Comment: @jfriend00 yes there is because when working with AWS Lambda functions the entire container will be "frozen" once you indicate that your function is done. This means that if fired off a request and then immediately called the lambda callback (`context.succeed()`) then the socket wouldn't even get a chance to open before the lambda container stopped executing. This is why you still need the callback for this function so that you can ensure the request was actually sent before the container is frozen.

Comment: @jfriend00 also this isn't processing the response at all. The error event handler is for if there was an error opening the socket and the end callback is to know when your request was sent successfully over the socket. It does not wait for a response from the server.